# What is the sentence trying to convey?

Tags: sentence-meaning, colons

Why is colon placed in the following sentence? What silence are they talking about?

**The nature of our sources may account for this silence : martyrs and confessors, through their sufferings, were purging themselves of their sins in this world.**

Comment: It must refer to something mentioned in a previous sentence.

Answer (score 1):

'This' refers to something mentioned in a previous sentence.

> The martyrs and confessors of the year Kihae accounted for roughly 1
> per cent of the Korean Christian community, but it is they who
> articulate most clearly the contempt for the world, the belief in a
> better life to come, the preoccupation with (sexual) sin and concern
> with God's judgement which have been identified as characteristic
> features of so-called `Tridentine' Catholicism." Such views,
> however, need to be set against a background of more mundane and
> communal activities, including prayer meetings and the distribution of
> charity in response to famine or persecution, and the intense
> eucharistic devotion displayed by the laity. Similarly, **none of the
> martyrs spoke of purgatory**, although the existence of prayers for
> the dead indicate that the Korean laity were exposed to that doctrine.
> The nature of our sources may account for **this silence** : martyrs
> and confessors, through their sufferings, were purging themselves of
> their sins in this world.

Page 578 - Journal of Ecclesiastical History, Vol. 51, No. 3, July 2000. A Persecuted Church: Roman Catholicism in Early Nineteenth-Century Korea by Andrew J. Finch

https://af.booksc.org/dl/53605536/dfd7c5

Comment: Well done for tracking it down!

Comment: @KateBunting - The bare sentence which is the subject of the question is given in a set of 'examples' under the Cambridge Dictionary definition of 'purging', but without any context whatsoever, just a link to the Cambridge English Corpus.

Comment: @KateBunting - my father told me, perfectly seriously, when I was aged seven, that as our family were Church of England, we didn't have to worry about Purgatory or Limbo.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Thanks for that. Please also tell what does 'nature of sources' mean here?

Comment: The colon after 'this silence' indicates that what follows is an explanation - '**the** nature of **our** sources' (of information) means '**the** particular types of sources of information' (that is, martyrs and confessors) 'available to **us**' (the authors of the article). These sources were not inclined to talk of purgatory because they were purging themselves of sin while still alive.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHarvey

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Just one more thing. Tell me how did you searched for the sentence and got this para?

Comment: I used Google for an exact-text search, by enclosing test in quotation marks.  I pasted this into Google **"The nature of our sources may account for this silence : martyrs and confessors, through their sufferings, were purging themselves of their sins in this world."** Part way down the page of results is this "A Persecuted Church: Roman Catholicism in Early Nineteenth-Century Korea | FINCH, ANDREW J. " with a link to a PDF of the article. Then I downloaded the PDF and searched within it for the first few words of your text in the question.